# How to do this replace command in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I will have names which are like:

Shoes - Red

How do I set up so all red ones in file would then become:

Red Shoes

I basically want to to move end text to the start of text.

Comment: I don't think this belongs to stackoverflow at all. The question concerns usage of a specific product and has only a very remote connection with programming. Maybe you could just try asking in some notepad++ -specific community or support forum?

Answer (score 2):

Use the find and replace with regular expression

**Find :** (Shoes) - (Red)

**replace with :** \1\2

Look at page http://blog.creativeitp.com/posts-and-articles/editors/understanding-regex-with-notepad

Answer (score 0):

Use find and Replace. `Ctrl + H`

Answer (score 0):

Consider using macros (assuming you have thousands of items to process).

Careful use of Home/End/Search/Copy/Paste can be used to find the '-' in the line, remove it, copy the text to the end of the line, come back to the front of the line, and paste it.

That way you don't have to do individual find/replaces for all the variants.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the first line, first column,
use `CTRL+H`
find **Shoes - Red**
replace **Red Shoes**
hit the **Replace All**
finished!

Answer (score 0):

More generally:

Find what: `^(\w+) - (\w+)$`
Replace with: `$2 $1`

If you have an old version of npp, you should do:

Replace with: `\2 \1`

**Explanation:**

```
The regular expression:

^(\w+) - (\w+)$

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   -                       ' - '
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```